# Prevent PyCharm from showing builtin modules on KeyboardInterrupt and other occasions

Tags: python, pycharm, built-in

In PyCharm when an Error occurs the IDE opens the module that produced the Error (this is especially annoying when the Error was produced by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

It also opens the module in which the program currently "is" when pausing in Debug mode. Is there a way to disable this behavior for built-in modules? (Preferably with a way of showing the exception anyway in case you *want* to see the source of the built-in module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accept the bounty as it pointed to the right direction:

applying the same trick to the file pydevd.py line 1793 finally solved it for me!!

```
        try:
          launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
        except:
          import traceback; traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I posted later [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613464/problems-when-showing-interpreter-ipython-after-running-program-in-pycharm) you can Edit PyDev's source to prevent parts of this from happening:

First, you have to find the source for the PyDev interactive interpreter (which is used by PyCharm). On my Windows machine it is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm\helpers\PyDev` (path my vary of course).

The problem can be fixed by editing the file `_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py` (in the PyDev source directory). Line 18 reads

```
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
```

wrap it in a `try ... except` block with the following code as exception handler

```
import traceback; traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it now breaks into : File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_file_utils.py", line 341, in GetFilenameAndBase

Comment: @Anona112 I haven't experienced this behaviour; I probably changed some other setting. but I don't remember anymore