# Problems when showing Interpreter (IPython) after running Program in PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, ipython, pycharm, pydev

I have PyCharm Professional Edition <strike>3.5</strike> 5.0 configured to

> use IPython when possible

and in my Run/Debug Configurations I set

> show interpreter afterwards

I use the interactive Interpreter a lot and I really like IPython, but there are some things that I don't like about the way this is handled in PyCharm:

- any `input()` in my programs return empty strings.
- Additionally, when an error occurs I can't interact with the Program anymore. (you can when you run a Python program with the `-i` flag)
- There is a lot of space between the last line in the Console and the current line

In IPython the `...:` prompt in a code block isn't indented 2 spaces and therefore not aligned to the `In [?]:` prompt.

- When an error occurs I get something like this:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 69, in <module>
>     globals = run_file(file, None, None)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 29, in run_file
>     pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>     exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
>   File "C:/Users/ca/Python/Bundeswettbewerb Informatik/Aufgabe2/Ameisen.py", line 133, in <module>
>     function_that_caused_error()
> ```

I don't need/want to see the traceback from the internals.

- When running a file IPython needs to be started which takes some seconds even if I'm not going use the interpreted afterwards. I would like PyCharm to start IPython after the program has ended or when I start debugging (you can start IPython in an interactive console by doing `import IPython; IPython.start_ipython()`

There are some other minor things that I don't like:

- When IPython is started it prints a lot of text to the console. I don't want to see any of it except maybe the version number (you can usually do this with the `--no-banner` option, but adding it to the interpreter options doesn't work)
- when you type something and press `Up` it replaces what I have written with the last item of my history instead of replacing it with the last item of my history that start with what I have typed. Plain IPython does this.
- I would like to have automatic code completion without having to press `Ctrl + Space` in the console

The "problems" are ordered by importance. Does anybody know how to change some of them? I could stop using IPython which would solve the second , the third and the fourth problem, but the other ones would still persist. All of this behavior (excluding the IPython stuff) is implemented very well in PyScripter.

## EDIT:

I have found solutions to the first two problems and the problem with the IPython banner. The source for the PyDev interactive interpreter (which is used by PyCharm) is located, on Windows, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PyCharm\helpers\PyDev` (path my vary of course).

So the first problem can be solved by editing the file `_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py`. Wrap line 18 (`exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)`) in a `try ... except` block with the following code as the exception handler `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()`. This will terminate your Python program if there is an error while letting you interact with the variable afterwards.

Problem 2 can be solved by editing the fire `pydev_run_in_console.py`. Add this import at the beginning of the file: `from pydev_console_utils import StdIn` and insert `sys.stdin = StdIn(interpreter, host, client_port)` after what was line 61 before adding the import.

In order to solve the problem with the banner you have to download the most recent version of the PyDev source [here](http://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pydev/pydev/PyDev%204.3.0/PyDev%204.3.0-sources.zip) and replace the files `pydev_ipython_console` and `pydev_ipython_console_011` by their newer versions. In the newer version of the first file the `__init__` method in line 22 has a argument called `show_banner` with the default value `True`. Change this to `False`.

Comment: I am intrigued by the bounty, but unfortunately I am at a loss as to what the question is. It sounds like you have bug reports/feature requests for pycharm?

Comment: @JonahGraham these aren't strictly bugs they are behaviour I would like to change. And I suppose that most of it can be changed, at least if you are willing to edit some source

Comment: You have already put in your +100 reps for this, I hope someone rewrites the code for you to do these things. However, I would still expect more luck on creating bug reports/feature requests with PyDev or PyCharm, especially as you are actually paying for PyCharm :-)

Comment: @JonahGraham I'm not paying for it; I'm a student

Comment: Do these things work better in PyDev in Eclipse - it certainly seems PyDev is more up to date that PyCharm. (as you are using pro edition of pycharm I assumed you were paying for it, well done getting a free license), finally I am not up on PyCharm versions (AFAIK they have three active major versions, 3.x, 4.x and 5.x, have you tried the 5.x to see if your issues are better there?)

Comment: It seems like a bug on pycharms/Ipythons consider contacting the developers or using just one of these softwares or export it to github or somthing, not likly to fix it but its somthing to try, try reinstalling python and your programs

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you are searching for, but based on my experience using `IPython` on InteliJ products ( `PyCharm`, `Ultimate`), **I don't recommend** using their version of `IPython`. It's full of bugs, outdated and you'll lose precious time fixing problems instead of coding.

Have you tried `jupyter notebook`? If you installed `python` with `anaconda`, it's already installed. To run it, open the terminal and type:

```
jupyter notebook
```

If your browser doesn't open automagically, head to http://localhost:8888

---

Note:

You can automate this process by creating `bat` or `sh` script containing the code above **inside your project directory**, this way it doesn't start on you home dir, which it does by default.

---

Resources:

- [How to Install and Use IPython](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/how-to-use-ipython)
- [nbopen project: Open a Jupyter notebook in the best available server](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen)

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, have you simply tried running a newer version of PyCharm and importing your settings? 3.5 is fairly outdated (I'm on 4.5.3 myself, newest version is 5.0) and I believe more support is offered for IPython in the newer versions. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/ipython.html. Especially if you are a student, it might not hurt to give it a shot. I know older versions of PyCharm were more buggy than recent releases.

Comment: yes I've already tried PyCharm 5.0 and I've updated the Question accordingly

Comment: Is IPython installed for your default project interpreter?

Comment: I've tested this in my Pycharm installation and it works once I pip install ipython. input() working fine too